# "SecurityError: The operation is insecure." in firefox and "Uncaught ReferenceError: openDialog is not defined" in chrome

Tags: javascript, opendialog

I tried

```
openDialog('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

and

```
openDialog('http://localhost');
```

Both throw an exception:

```
  SecurityError: The operation is insecure
```

in firefox and

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: openDialog is not defined
```

in chrome

*openDialog()* is not available in all browsers?

I am working on a local machine.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.openDialog) says `Not part of any standard.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [window.openDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.openDialog) is an extension to [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open). It behaves the
>   same, except that it can optionally take one or more parameters past
>   windowFeatures, and windowFeatures itself is treated a little
>   differently.

So, If you are not using the additional arguments use something like :

```
window.open(
   "http://localhost",
   "DescriptiveWindowName",
   "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes"
 );
```

or simply

```
window.open("http://localhost");
```

---

> If the strWindowFeatures parameter is used, the features that are not
>   listed will be disabled or removed (except titlebar and close which
>   are by default yes).

So yes, nothing possible for the titlebar or close button.

Comment: I want a simple window. don't want any decorations like titlebar, menubar, etc. or reduce the decoration as much as possible.

Comment: @habeebperwad Do see my edits there will be no scroll/status bars. Also visit the window.open link, you can find the list of all the features which you can control while opening the new window...

Comment: @habeebperwad In the window features string add "toolbar=yes"

Comment: I don't want the address bar also.